# FoxNetSoft.SimpleCheckout route only works for logged in customers

Tags: plugins, routes, nopcommerce

I have an eCommerce site where ordinary customers (B2C) checkout as guests, and other retailers (B2B) checkout as logged-in customers. I'm using FoxNetSofts SimpleCheckout plugin to do this.

For logged-in customers ("customers") this works splendidly. They are sent to the route "Checkout" which sends them to the URL /simplecheckout and loads the FoxNetSoft plugin page.

For guests, however, this does not work. They are sent to the route "Checkout", which sends them to the url /cart/ and loads the standard nop cart.

As far as I can tell, all settings are correct. I have not manually changed any routes.

I have tracked the problem to cart validation, and cart errors.

```
2016.01.26 09:58:02:3077*******
SimpleCheckout. Start.
2016.01.26 09:58:02:3480*******
Validation (cart). Warnings.
shoppingcart.selectattribute
```

EDIT: I managed to solve my own problem. It stemmed from a missing Checkout Attribute, which was set as required in the admin backend. Since the attribute was missing I was redirected to my cart to solve the problem. It thus had nothing to do with the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own problem. It stemmed from a missing Checkout Attribute, which was set as required in the admin backend. Since the attribute was missing I was redirected to my cart to solve the problem. It thus had nothing to do with the plugin.